# How to properly use .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been recently started learning jQuery and am having some problems.
The code format of jQuery is unfamiliar due to me coming from a background of C/C++.

So, my problem is that .append() simply seems not to be appending. I have recently been working on a script to make a popup in jQuery, and needed to append an element to body. Nothing happened. After further testing .append() didn't seem to work. My conclusion is I'm probably misusing it but I'm unaware of how.

```
$('#contact').click(function (e) {
    $('#about').append('<h1>test</h1>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Edit 1: Html was requested

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canteen Mate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "nav_wrapper" id = "nav_wrapper">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class = "current"><a href="#nav_wrapper" id = "Home" class =      "nav">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" id = "About" class = "nav">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" id = "Contact" class = "nav">Contact</a>    </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class = "wrapper">
  <img src="images/newfood.jpg" alt="Food" class="luncho">
  <div class = "text">
    <h1 class = "motto">Ordering from the canteen has never been so simple<br>
    <p class = "motto-description" id = "about">Order food from your canteen from
    anywhere as long as you have data.</p></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only some of the html was included to save space (the html in the area I'm appending to).
The `<script>` element is at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ids in your html are capitalized (`Contact`, not `contact`), but you're using all lowercase in your JavaScript. Change the jQuery selectors too:

```
$('#Contact').click(function (e) {
    $('#About').append('<h1>test</h1>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or make the ids lowercase in HTML:

```
<a href="#about" id="about" class="nav">About</a>
<a href="#contact" id="contact" class="nav">Contact</a>
```

Comment: That seems to be a vital the issue, well spotted

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much! I looked at the href because I'm an idiot. Must have forgotten my coffee! Thank you @eisbehr

Comment: Sorry, but you made a mistake and now vote negative. The problem is yours, I make you see the code works.

Comment: Isn't stack overflow a learning resource @Laurianti ? No need for the negativity.

Comment: Good spot, @eisbehr! I think the point about making the `id` attributes lower case should be the first point, though - it's the most common naming convention to use: `lowerCamelCase` :)

Comment: My answer was the first with working code with "Snippet". It was useful to show you the code working. You made a error, not me.

Comment: @JamesBalajan If this answer solved your problem, i recommend you [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to show that to the community.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder People should provide feedback for negs, and I think it should be mandatory. Peeps on here will not learn if they keep just getting negs. What was wrong/what did you try. SO does say as a neg is submitted and I find it common courtesy to do so. Someone has just come along here and left a load of negs without really any thought and that is just as bad, if not worse than the original answer.

Comment: @Laurianti Actually you were the second to post a snippet. cars10 beat you to it by 4 minutes, which meant he got an extra 4 minutes of downvotes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was to test your self your code working, ok for the downvoted. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('#contact').click(function (e) {
    $('#about').append('<h1>test</h1>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about">this is div "about".</div>
<div id="contact">click here to see some action</div>
```

Comment: Because [stating that you cannot reproduce the problem described in the question is not an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -3):

Your code seems fine. Make sure that you also have those divs in HTML.
Here is the JSFiddle I did with your code and it works perfectly fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/edtqpvym/

The HTML i used to test

```
<span id="contact">Click me</span>
<div id="about">
</div>
```

EDIT:
You must take care of uppercase and lowercase letters! In HTML you are naming the div ID's with uppercase and in JQuery you are calling them with lowercase. That solves your problem. It is good practice to name divs with lower case letters. And also you shouldn't use spaces before =

```
id = "Contact" class = "nav"
```

Write it like this:

```
id="Contact" class="nav"
```

Your code could get really messy if you stick to that spacing.